# jQuery fire a custom event

Tags: jquery

Is there a way to fire up an event

```
.on('input',function() {});
```

attached event from jquery function?

I want to do something like:

```
$('#field').onInput();
```

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/trigger/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [.trigger()](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/)

```
$('#field').trigger('input');
```